# Integral of $\int x^{-x} dx$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, exponential-function, taylor-expansion, indefinite-integrals

Question: $\int x^{-x} dx =$ ?

Hint: 
$$ e^{x\ln \frac{1}{x}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^n$$

I figure since $\int x^{-x} dx = \int e^{x\ln \frac{1}{x}} dx$, maybe I should find the correlation between $\int e^{x\ln \frac{1}{x}} dx$ and $\int e^{-x\ln \frac{1}{x}} dx$. But I still can't think of the connection between the two

I used WolframAlpha to solve it but it didn't show the process

Comment: The stated hint is false. That sum actually equals $$\frac{1}{x} = \int \frac{-1}{x^2}.$$

Comment: Maybe you made an error in typing out the hint?

Comment: @6005 My edit was approved

Comment: @BCLC I am not sure I would have approved your edit. It changes the meaning of the question to something that may not have been intended (and the new hint doesn't seem necessarily helpful to me.)

Comment: @6005 You said the hint was false. I corrected it and now it is right?

Comment: @BCLC Who knows if the OP intended this, though? In general edits which change the meaning of a post are discouraged.

Comment: If it were just a matter of a minus sign or a missing $x^n$ I would have no problem. But you removed an integral and added an $x^n$ so at that point it is not entirely clear that that is what was originally intended.

Comment: Ya, at first I also thought "this looks like a Taylor expansion but with an integral and without $x^n$". That's why I'm confused. I'm just copying what is written in my exercise paper and yes, it may be wrong, but I think the question is intended to be like that

Comment: @user3429874 Are you looking for closed form? If not, just integrate the series as I tried below, I guess

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that we should use the hint and then swap integral and summation (if we can?) so the main issue would be to evaluate:

$$\int x^n [\ln(\frac{1}{x})]^n dx \ \ (\text{removed the} \frac{1}{n!})$$

Not sure if I'm right but it seems helpful to repeated integration by parts to arrive at what I think should be:

$$ [\ln(\frac{1}{x})]^n \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + [n \ln(\frac{1}{x})]^{n-1} \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2} + [n (n-1) \ln(\frac{1}{x})]^{n-2} \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^3} + \dots + [n! \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^n}]$$

Edit: Or evaluate:

$$\int x^n [\ln(x)]^n dx \ \ (\text{removed the} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!})$$

I think that's

$$\frac{(\ln x)^n x^{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{(\ln x)^{n-1} (n) x^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)} + ... \text{something}$$

Comment: This seems like a good route. Hmm

Comment: @6005 Thanks! Wasn't so sure hahaha