# Can someone help me find $\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{x^{x}} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

In particular I'm trying to find the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x^x}$, I still didn't manage to do calculate it. Wolfram alpha says "no results found", what can I do?

Comment: While it has no elementary derivative, you can integrate it on e.g. $[0,\,1]$ easily.

Comment: According to my memory, such an antiderivative cannot be expressed in elementary functions. But it is strange that Wolfram Alpha should give you such an answer.

Comment: @Trebor: what is strange ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513212/integral-of-int-x-x-dx

Comment: @YvesDaoust For such a famous integral, it ought to have given more information.

Comment: "what can I do ?": accept what Alpha tells you.

Comment: @Trebor: When you submit a function, Alpha is not acting as an encyclopedia and trying to "recognize" the function. It is doing a systematic study, including antiderivative, using general algorithms. In any case, there is nothing more to say than "no closed-form antiderivative".

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there was a function that I don't know the 4 letter meaning $$\text{Sphd}(x,a)$$  I don't remember where I saw it.  But this function seemed to solve things like integral of $x ^ x.$

Comment: Well, @lone, you can always define ${\rm Algoak}(t)$ by ${\rm Algoak}(t)=\int_0^tx^x\,dx$ and then claim you've solved the problem, but you won't fool anyone that way.

Comment: @lonestudent The problem of computing the definite integrals of $x^{x}$ and $x^{-x}$ in $[0,1]$ is known as the "Sophomore's dream" (hence your shorthand). By extension, there is indeed this function $\text{Sphd}$ that is the antiderivative in $[0,x]$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson As far as I remember, $x ^ x$ is just a special case for the function I gave you.  By the way, have you seen the function in this name?

Comment: @lone, there's still no challenge in making a useless definition that has an antiderivative of $x^x$ as a special case. I bet you could do it, if you wanted to.  Have I seen "Sphd"? No.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream

Comment: Inventing a function being the antiderivate of $\frac{1}{x^x}$ is the same as it was done for the inverse of $x\cdot e^x$ which led to the Lambert-W-function. Does that mean that we have solved the problem to find the inverse of $x\cdot e^x$ ? No ! The Lambert-W-function must still be calculated numerically, approximations can be found in tables.

Comment: @Peter shall I say simpler ones? :) $\log_5{7}, \sqrt 3 ...$

Comment: @GerryMyerson I remembered something.  I have never used math software.  I remember once seeing **Maple** giving the integral of $ x ^ x$ as a Hypergeometric function.

Comment: @lonestudent ... I think you are mistaken about Maple.

Comment: By starting with the identity $x^{-x}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n x^n \log ^n(x)}{n!}$ I quickly obtained the generalised definite integral result $$\int_0^s x^{-x} \, dx=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(n+1)^{-n-1} \Gamma (n+1,-((n+1) \log (s)))}{n!}$$ using Mathematica, that involves the incomplete gamma function, $\Gamma(a,b)$. Any use?